# A point P moves so that AP and BP are perpendicular. Find the equation of the locus of P

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

A point p(x,y) moves so that AP and BP are perpendicular, given A=(3,2) and B =(-4,1). Find the equation of the locus of P.

Can someone please advise me on what to do for this question. Just need a direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Direction:* The locus is the circle with diameter $AB$.

Comment: So I would need to find the distance of AB. But then what else?

Comment: The midpoint of $AB$ will be the center of the circle.

Comment: the distance is a surd 5root 2

Comment: and (-1/2 , 3/2) Although my answer is nothing like answer

Comment: You have $2r$ and $(a,b)$. Then the equation of the circle is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

At each stage, and since the product of slopes of perpendicular lines is $\;-1\;$ , we get:

$$\frac{y-2}{x-3}=-\frac{x+4}{y-1}\iff y^2-3y+2=-x^2-x+12\iff$$

$$\iff\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\left(y-\frac32\right)^2-\frac52=10\;\;\ldots\ldots$$